# Problem "Didn't find PN53x board" in Arduino Uno E-Card Reader

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide, code-review, rfid

This is component to make E-Card reader, using arduino uno pn532 
[image]
[image]

**Code**

```
  if (success) {
    // Display some basic information about the card
    Serial.println("Found an ISO14443A card");
    Serial.print("  UID Length: ");Serial.print(uidLength, DEC);Serial.println(" bytes");
    Serial.print("  UID Value: ");
    nfc.PrintHex(uid, uidLength);
    Serial.println("");

    if (uidLength == 4)
    {
      // We probably have a Mifare Classic card ... 
      Serial.println("Seems to be a Mifare Classic card (4 byte UID)");

      // Now we need to try to authenticate it for read/write access
      // Try with the factory default KeyA: 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF
      Serial.println("Trying to authenticate block 4 with default KEYA value");
      uint8_t keya[6] = { 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF };

      // Start with block 4 (the first block of sector 1) since sector 0
      // contains the manufacturer data and it's probably better just
      // to leave it alone unless you know what you're doing
      success = nfc.mifareclassic_AuthenticateBlock(uid, uidLength, 4, 0, keya);

      if (success)
      {
        Serial.println("Sector 1 (Blocks 4..7) has been authenticated");
        uint8_t data[16];

        // If you want to write something to block 4 to test with, uncomment
        // the following line and this text should be read back in a minute
        //memcpy(data, (const uint8_t[]){ 'a', 'd', 'a', 'f', 'r', 'u', 'i', 't', '.', 'c', 'o', 'm', 0, 0, 0, 0 }, sizeof data);
        //success = nfc.mifareclassic_WriteDataBlock (4, data);

        // Try to read the contents of block 4
        success = nfc.mifareclassic_ReadDataBlock(4, data);

        if (success)
        {
          // Data seems to have been read ... spit it out
          Serial.println("Reading Block 4:");
          nfc.PrintHexChar(data, 16);
          Serial.println("");

          // Wait a bit before reading the card again
          delay(1000);
        }
        else
        {
          Serial.println("Ooops ... unable to read the requested block.  Try another key?");
        }
      }
      else
      {
        Serial.println("Ooops ... authentication failed: Try another key?");
      }
    }

    if (uidLength == 7)
    {
      // We probably have a Mifare Ultralight card ...
      Serial.println("Seems to be a Mifare Ultralight tag (7 byte UID)");

      // Try to read the first general-purpose user page (#4)
      Serial.println("Reading page 4");
      uint8_t data[32];
      success = nfc.mifareultralight_ReadPage (4, data);
      if (success)
      {
        // Data seems to have been read ... spit it out
        nfc.PrintHexChar(data, 4);
        Serial.println("");

        // Wait a bit before reading the card again
        delay(1000);
      }
      else
      {
        Serial.println("Ooops ... unable to read the requested page!?");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And i find problem, like this :

[image]

**EDIT:**
Now has ben change to I2C mode and detected RFID. But not detected E-Card:

[image]
How solve this is problem?

Comment: are you trying to communicate with it using SPI or I2C? You seem to have I2C connections AND half SPI

Comment: Oh, wait - you're using HSU mode? The DIP switches look like they're in HSU mode. But, you seem to have SDA connected to SCL and SCL connected to SDA if you were thinking you're using I2C - so, all in all, your wiring is completely wrong

Comment: The pictures show, a) board is in HSU (uart) mode, and b) SCL and SDA are "cross" connected - so, very useful actually :p

Comment: Now has ben change to I2C mode and detected RFID. But not detected E-Card..

Comment: Post your code, one that show the problem.

Comment: it is under sir, code..

Comment: does the code get as far as `Display some basic information about the card`

Comment: I'd remove the photos now - no need for photos in this question

Comment: To be blunt: We need the code **before** the code you posted too...

Comment: code too long, to post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if (success) {
    // Display some basic information about the card
    Serial.println("Found an ISO14443A card");
    Serial.print("  UID Length: ");Serial.print(uidLength, DEC);Serial.println(" bytes");
    Serial.print("  UID Value: ");
    nfc.PrintHex(uid, uidLength);
    Serial.println("");

```
if (uidLength == 4)
{
  // We probably have a Mifare Classic card ... 
  Serial.println("Seems to be a Mifare Classic card (4 byte UID)");

  // Now we need to try to authenticate it for read/write access
  // Try with the factory default KeyA: 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF
  Serial.println("Trying to authenticate block 4 with default KEYA value");
  uint8_t keya[6] = { 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF };

  // Start with block 4 (the first block of sector 1) since sector 0
  // contains the manufacturer data and it's probably better just
  // to leave it alone unless you know what you're doing
  success = nfc.mifareclassic_AuthenticateBlock(uid, uidLength, 4, 0, keya);

  if (success)
  {
    Serial.println("Sector 1 (Blocks 4..7) has been authenticated");
    uint8_t data[16];

    // If you want to write something to block 4 to test with, uncomment
    // the following line and this text should be read back in a minute
    //memcpy(data, (const uint8_t[]){ 'a', 'd', 'a', 'f', 'r', 'u', 'i', 't', '.', 'c', 'o', 'm', 0, 0, 0, 0 }, sizeof data);
    //success = nfc.mifareclassic_WriteDataBlock (4, data);

    // Try to read the contents of block 4
    success = nfc.mifareclassic_ReadDataBlock(4, data);

    if (success)
    {
      // Data seems to have been read ... spit it out
      Serial.println("Reading Block 4:");
      nfc.PrintHexChar(data, 16);
      Serial.println("");

      // Wait a bit before reading the card again
      delay(1000);
    }
    else
    {
      Serial.println("Ooops ... unable to read the requested block.  Try another key?");
    }
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.println("Ooops ... authentication failed: Try another key?");
  }
}

if (uidLength == 7)
{
  // We probably have a Mifare Ultralight card ...
  Serial.println("Seems to be a Mifare Ultralight tag (7 byte UID)");

  // Try to read the first general-purpose user page (#4)
  Serial.println("Reading page 4");
  uint8_t data[32];
  success = nfc.mifareultralight_ReadPage (4, data);
  if (success)
  {
    // Data seems to have been read ... spit it out
    nfc.PrintHexChar(data, 4);
    Serial.println("");

    // Wait a bit before reading the card again
    delay(1000);
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.println("Ooops ... unable to read the requested page!?");
  }
}
```

}
}

Comment: Why are you adding **answers** - edit your question, remove the answers

Answer (score 0):

This is sir, i check using white card

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Stop posting answers! Edit your answer!